# Issue with jQuery .one() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I've got a container that includes several icons the user can hover over and be shown a block of text next to it.  I'm grabbing the blocks of text from an array and have a randomize function so that they're always shown a different block of text when revisiting the page.

I ran into an issue where every time you hover over an icon, it keeps adding more array elements, because the function gets called each time you hover over the icon.  So I decided to use the one() method so the function only runs once, however that's where my *real* issue is.  Using the one() method doesn't show ANY text, and I'm pretty sure it's due to the nested function I have.

You can test this out here: http://www.evanvolmering.com/bootstrap/docs/examples/carousel/eyeswideshut.html

In the banner a video will play, and shortly into it a little icon will appear in the bottom of left of the banner.  Hovering over it will show some text.  When you hover over it again it adds another array item, and so on.  It works, but I don't want it to keep adding array items.

10 seconds later another icon will appear to the top right, which currently has the one() method applied to it.  As you can see nothing happens when you hover over it.  Not sure where to go from here.

**My randomize code (which I got from another StackOverflow answer):**

```
var numRandoms = 14;
function makeUniqueRandom() {
   if (!uniqueRandoms.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < numRandoms; i++) {
         uniqueRandoms.push(i);
      }
   }
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueRandoms.length);
   var val = uniqueRandoms[index];
   uniqueRandoms.splice(index, 1);
   return val;
}
```

My code which currently 'works' but keeps adding more array items on hover:

```
     $('img.button1').hover(function(){
     $('p.trivia1').fadeIn("slow");
     $( 'p.trivia1' ).append(makeUniqueRandom());
},
    function(){
    $("p.trivia1").stop().fadeOut("slow");
});
```

My code that uses one() but doesn't do anything on hover:

```
    $('img.button2').one("hover",function(){
         $('p.trivia2').fadeIn("slow");
    $( 'p.trivia2' ).append(makeUniqueRandom());
},
    function(){
    $("p.trivia2").stop().fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: The problem with `one('hover')` is that `hover` isn't an event. It's a shorthand method for two events - namely `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. You need to use whichever one of those is applicable for your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mouseenter/mouseleave instead of hover

```
  $('img.button1').on('mouseenter',function(){
     $('p.trivia1').fadeIn("slow");
     $( 'p.trivia1' ).append(makeUniqueRandom());
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $("p.trivia1").stop().fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: This still had the effect that every time you hovered over an icon, it would keep adding more and more items to the array.  However for now I've gone with your solution except I changed the first 'on' to 'one', which stops it from adding array items at the cost of showing nothing on repeated hovers.

Comment: you need to do a condition to test if the makeUniqueRandom is appended to the item if it is just toggle fade it